# RichFaces calendar configuration - display icon only(without input field)

Tags: jsf, input, calendar, richfaces, hide

How can I show icon only for `rich:calendar` component?

I needn't any input,just icon.

Will be great if it's standard attribute,instead of CSS configuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute showInput="false".

```
        <rich:calendar 
        id="date2"
        popup="true"
        cellHeight="12px"
        cellWidth="12px"
        locale="en/US"
        datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
        showApplyButton="false"
        zindex="2000"
        showFooter="false"
        required="true"
        enableManualInput="true"
        showInput="false" />
```

Comment: Hi Dave, where can i find all those options? i tried searching for the rich:calendar api. all i get are simple examples.

Comment: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf?tab=info&cid=482137